# jenkins shell user groups and normal shell user group is different

Tags: jenkins, usergroups

I am running "jenkins" on `CentOS`.

After build, I want to copy binary to my shared directory, so I add "jenkins" user into my "personal" group.

In the normal shell, it runs ID command and it shows "jenkins"'s group is both "jenkins" and "personal", but I run ID command on `Execute Shell` on "jenkins" projects, it shows only "jenkins" group.

I don't know why it does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that you started jenkins before you added the jenkins user to the personal group.  Group information is read when the shell is invoked (or in this case when the daemon is started) and is not re-read if/when changed. To fix this you simply need to restart jenkins, on centos that's:

```
/etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```